# value semantic tricks in C++

Tags: c++, oop, programming-languages, semantics

Apart from C++ (because he has operator overload), do you know another OOP language that can do (or emulate in the worst case)  "value semantics" ?

Answer (score 3):

In C# if you define your "object" as a `struct` it has value semantic. If you define it as a `class` it has reference semantic (unless you make it immutable, like `string`, then its semantic is more similar to the value one).

I'll add that it's quite easy to break this "implicit" semantic.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public StringBuilder SB;
}

MyStruct a = new MyStruct();
a.SB = new StringBuilder();

MyStruct b = a;
```

now you have broken the semantic, because both `a` and `b` "point" to the same reference.

Comment: That didn't break value semantics at all. In fact, that's exactly what value semantics says should happen.

Answer (score 0):

structs in D also have value semantics.